# Where does QGIS Plugin "Customize Toolbar" save its changes?

Tags: qgis, windows, linux, toolbar, qgis-customization

Where does the qgis plugin *Cutomize Toolbar* save its changes in the system?

Operating Systems are Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @eurojam](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286163/where-does-qgis-plugin-customize-toolbar-save-its-changes/345600#comment458573_286163):

> there is a file called `.CustomToolBars` in the `user/home` directory.
>   under windows this is `c:\user\username`

and [by @SimonHaufe (the asker)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286163/where-does-qgis-plugin-customize-toolbar-save-its-changes/345600#comment458609_286163):

> Under Linux it is the same path: `/home`. There you can find a file called `.CustomToolBars`.