# Customize Toolbar - customize location of savings

Tags: qgis, qgis-customization

In [Where does QGIS Plugin "Customize Toolbar" save its changes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286163) it was pointed out, that "Customize Toolbars" saves the changes in a file called ".CustomToolBars". This file is stored in the home directory of the user, so the path is something like "c:\users\xyz"

I am running a mobile version of QGIS and I would like to change the location  of this file to the current directory where the plugin is installed (or any other directory  on the USB drive). I use this mobile version for teaching and need to have the path set dynamically so the file will be found no matter  of the path of the mobile QGIS.

I have only very little knowledge of programming (and especially Python), but I had a look at the python code and I think that the code lines for defining the location are to be found in line 50 and 51 of "CustomToolbar.py":

```
[50] self.userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
[51] self.filepath = self.userhome + '//.CustomToolBars'
```

In order to set the location dynamically to the current directory of the plugin I changed it as follows:

```
[50] self.userhome = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

But when starting QGIS it fails to load the plugin and gives the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/GIS/usbgis/apps/qgis2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)

File "H:\GIS\usbgis\config_lite/python/plugins\CustomToolBar\__init__.py", line 10, in classFactory
    from CustomToolbar import CustomToolbar

  File "H:/GIS/usbgis/apps/qgis2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

  File "H:\GIS\usbgis\config_lite/python/plugins\CustomToolBar\CustomToolbar.py", line 52
    self.userhome = os.path.dirname(__file__)
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Actually, I am a bit lost and don't quite know how proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem by myself - it was just caused by my lacking knowledge of Python and the importance of the indents. The error message "Indention Error: unexpected indent" gave me the hint to search deeper for the problem...

The error occured because I did a copy & paste in Notepad++ of line [50] to change it exactly the way I suggested in my post. I did make a copy of the code line because a wanted to keep the original code commented out by # as a fallback.

What I did not know was, that copy & paste of code lines apparently does not keep the original indents and makes blanks...

So, when I assured that the indents were correct the script worked exactly as I wanted it: it set the path to the ".CustomToolbar"-file to the current directory of the plugin.

By the way, this changing of the variable "self.userhome" also has to be made in line [54] the script "CustomToolbarDialog.py". By this the saving path is also set dynamically to the current directory of the plugin.